# How to select multiple lines until a determinate character?

Tags: vim, emacs, editor

I would like to select multiple line until a determinate character, like in the image below  where the special character is for this example is `=`.

[image]

I've tried with VIM ctrl+v/ but doesn't work.This is the example:

```
global Tint=spettro.readlines()[3].split(",")[1]
global Average=spettro.readlines()[4].split(",")[1]
global Sensor_Mode=spettro.readlines()[6].split(",")[1]
global Case_Temperature=spettro.readlines()[7].split(",")[1]
global Sensor_Temperature=spettro.readlines()[8].split(",")[1]
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `emacs`? Do you want a solution for that, too?

Comment: @GregHendershott I simply want a solution for my problem no matter how ,I can use both editor so if in emacs is more easy I can use it...

Answer (score 2):

You can't in Vim. There's *blockwise visual selection* (via `<C-V>`), but this is restricted to **rectangular** blocks, expect for a selection (with `$`) that goes to the end of all covered lines, where a "jagged right edge" is possible.

Since selection in itself is of little value, you probably want to **do** something with it. There are alternatives, e.g. `:substitute` or `:global` commands with a pattern that selects up to the first `=`: `/^[^=]*/`

To yank the text, I'd use this (there are different approaches, too; note that you need to adapt the range inside the `getline()`):

```
:let @@ = join(map(getline(1, '$'), 'matchstr(v:val,"^[^=]*")'), "\n")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I try your code and it doesn't work can you explain me how to copy the code from `global` to `=`for example. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just gave hints, no working example, but now I've added one approach for yanking.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) plug-in.

Then, to select in those three lines:

- `/=<cr>`  go to the first '='
- `<c-n>`  start multiple cursors mode
- `<c-n>`  create a new cursor and jump to the second '='
- `<c-n>`  create a new cursor and jump to the third '='
- `ho0`  select everything before the '='

Deleting and changing the selection seems to work fine. I do not know whether or not yanking is possible, too.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el

I haven't played with it much, but it can probably do what you want.  Look at the video.

You can probably achieve your end goal with regex replacement (and maybe a keyboard macro), but you haven't stated what the end goal is.  It's generally better to ask how to change one chunk of code into another, and not assume some technique (e.g. multiple selections).